# Returning value when calling instance python

Tags: python, class, call

I was wondering how to achieve this behavior.

When you call a variable in python, it directly displays some value.

like:

```
>> a= 5
>> a
5
```

libraries like numpy also do this

```
>> a = np.array([1,2])
>> a
>> array([1,2])
```

Happens something like that right?
So i want to emulate that behaviour  to build a class

```
class example(object):
   def __init__(self,intputs):
       self.out = inputs
...
instance = example(inputs)
```

such that when i write

```
instance
```

it were directly equivalent to do

```
instance.out
```

Cos the most similar thing I know is setting **call** to do that but in that case it would be calling instance() with those brackets

Comment: The interactive shell (i.e. the REPL) is actually what's printing the value, not the Python interpreter.

Comment: Did you meant instance = example(inputs)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why you want to do this. The proper way to handle printing out the value of a class instance is to provide either a `__str__` or `__repr__` method for your class (depending on what exactly you want to see), call that method, and print the result. For most cases, a simple `__str__` call will suffice:

```
class example(object):
    def __init__(self,intputs):
        # your init code here

    def __str__(self):
        # construct a string for the class value and return it
        return str(self.some_value)
```

You would then do something like the following to get the string representation in your code:

```
instance = example(some_value)
print(str(instance))
```

Here's [a helpful article](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/__str__-vs-__repr) and [relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr) on the difference between `__str__` and `__repr__`.